# Meaning of fr and sub in Logic Pro X timestamp

Tags: rhythm, daw, logic-pro

Logic Pro X shows me this:

[image]

1 second, 15 fr and 56 sub?

How do I convert that into seconds?

Comment: Frames and subframes, google SMPTE timecode.

Comment: @replete that's way to complex for me; there are a "random" number (commonly 24, 25, 29.97 or 30) "fr" in each second, and "sub" is about frame-dropping? I just want to know how I can convert that ^^ into literal seconds :c

Comment: It is possible to show milliseconds or samples instead of “bits” (aka subframes) in the time display. That way you don’t have to convert at all. See: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13440?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [SMPTE timecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_timecode). `fr` is frame number. `sub` is subframe giving higher granularity. To convert this information to seconds you need to know your framerate. Logic Pro uses a value of 80 subframes per frame, so to convert `frame` and `subframe` to seconds use `(frame + subframe/80) / framerate`. For example, if your framerate is 24, then you have `(15 + 56/80) / 24 = 0.654` seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Is there a setting in Logic to display the seconds converted from frames and subframes so that we don't have to do the math on the side? It'd be useful to see in realtime for example when selecting section with the marquee tool.